# Tkinter - can't find package treectrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, listbox, tkinter

Well I wanted to try using multi-column `ListBox` in `Tkinter`,
and I came to find "`TkTreectrl"` which was suggested here,
but the problem is, when I try using it and creating a `MultiListbox`,
I'm getting this error:

> "_tkinter.TclError: can't find package treectrl"

Any ideas what to do? 
thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have the treectrl package? http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So now I figured I need to put it in tcl folder or smth, and after doin that I'm getting that Error: > _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load library "C:/Python27/tcl/treectrl24.dll": inval
id argument

Comment: have a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52356345/2160507

Comment: damn that's old

Answer (score 0):

Download 64 or x86 bit `tktreectrl` (depending upon system arch) from this below link :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktreectrl/files/tktreectrl/tktreectrl-2.4.1/

Put it in `tcl` folder (e.g your conda directory where you get this error --`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\tcl\`)

You will get rid of two types of of error:

1. Can't find package error
2. Invalid argument Error