# Is there any way to fix the column width in listbox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I want to show some items in listbox. Some are very short and some are very large(10-15 characters). Like below one,

```
1. facebook  gowtham95****@gmail.com

2. gmail  someone@gmail.com

3. stackoverflow   stackusername
```

I want to show them neatly like...

```
1. facebook    gowtham95****@gmail.com

2. gmail       someone@gmail.com

3. stack..     stackusername
```

Is there anyway to fix the column width in listbox in Tkinter?

and onemore thing, I want to label it above as id, domain and username. I don't want to use labels. I want to mention it in listbox itself, is there anyway?

Comment: Maybe try [TkinterTreeCtrl](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/). See screenshots: [TkTreeCtrl](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Thank you for that. But, in windows I'm unable to do that using tcltreectrl library. Imported successfully. But, while creating listbox, it's saying 

tcl error: can't find package tcltreectrl

any suggestions ???

Comment: listboxes don't have columns, so no, there is no way to fix the width of a column in a listbox. How are you trying to create the "columns"? Are you actually using the treeview widget? (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Comment: No, I'm using spaces. I import data from sqlite3 database file.

 
"for row in cursor: row[0] + ' ' * 10 + row[1]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) - but it requires some [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), and you have to find the longest string in column(s).

```
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('600x100')

lb = tk.Listbox(master, font='monospace') # some monospaced font
lb.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

#---

data = [
    ('1', 'facebook', 'gowtham95****@gmail.com'),
    ('2', 'gmail', 'someone@gmail.com'),
    ('3', 'stackoverflow', 'stackusername')
]

longest_1 = max( len(x[1]) for x in data )
longest_2 = max( len(x[2]) for x in data )

for x in data:
    line = '%s | %*s | %*s |' % (x[0], -longest_1, x[1], -longest_2, x[2])    
    lb.insert(tk.END, line)

#---

tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Need to know, one thing. If in case, if a entry length is more, like "somethingtobedisplayeed" , I want it to be displayed as "somethin..". Is it possible  with the above one?

Comment: You have to change "somethingtobedisplayeed" to "somethin.." on your own before you insert it into Listbox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872512/python-truncate-a-long-string

Comment: how to use treectrl or named something?

I'm getting error after installing.

Comment: I didn't use it. Did you install [TkTreeCtrl](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/) ? Tkinter is wrapper on Tcl/Tk so you need to install TkTreeCtrl (for Tcl) and TkinterTreeCtrl (for Python) to use it.

Comment: Yeah, I installed it and imported successfully too. But when I used it in my program I got the error.

Comment: I found only this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984676/tkinter-cant-find-package-treectrl - see in comments

Comment: I read it. One more question, under windows my menu background or foreground colour is not changing. For the same program, when I run in on linux, it changed and working according to my program. Is there anything I need additionally in windows ?

Comment: I don't know - I don't use Windows. Maybe ask [Bryan Oakley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) - he is Master of Tkinter :)

Comment: I use linux. I'm just making a windows executable. Thanks for helping me.