# Anaconda/Spyder using TkTreeCtrl

Tags: module, installation, anaconda, spyder

I try to use TkTreeCtrl with Spyder. I downloaded the files from:
http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/

and put them into this folder:

\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\tcl

But I cant use it. What am I missing here?

Kind regards!

Answer (score -1):

it seems that you need to also:

1. Download the TkinterTreectrl package from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkintertreectrl/files)
2. Unzip it
3. Open the Anaconda Prompt
4. Navigate to the unziped folder
5. run the following command: ***python setup.py install***

Hope it helps.